# Difference between two dates and if one date is null use current day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have to find difference between two contract dates. Basically between effective date and end date. But what if the contract is still on so I want the present day.(Time Stamp)? How can i combine both in SQL
eg:

```
start d: 1/1/17 end date: 2/1/17 effective days 31
start d: 1/1/17 end date: null  effective days: total days to date.
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,ISNULL(EndDate,GETDATE())`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( day, 
                 [start], 
                 COALESCE ([end], GETDATE())
               )
```

Comment: `COALESCE` has only one `L`

Comment: yay `sql server` silver badge :)

Comment: Congratulations on the SQL Server badge  -- well deserved achievment.

Comment: Thanks Juan, but how does SQL knows to select GETDATE for null values

Comment: that is [**COALESCE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) job, that function return the first not null vaule. In this case if the first value is `NULL` then use the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expressions to compare values with each other and then use functions such as `getdate()` to return the current date and time.

```
select getdate()           -- Will return the date and time of right now

      ,case when 1 < 2
            then 'Less'
            else 'Greater'
            end            -- This will return the value 'Less'

      ,case when YourDateField < getdate()
            then YourDateField
            else getdate()
            end            --  This will return the earliest of YourDateField or right now
```

Instead of using the slightly verbose `case` when simply checking to see if a value is `null` or not, you can also use one of the two shorthand functions `isnull` and `coalesce`.  `isnull` checks just the one value and `coalesce` returns the first not `null` value from a list (There are other differences, but I will leave that up to you to research):

```
select isnull(YourPopulatedDateField,getdate())              -- Will return YourPopulatedDateField
      ,isnull(YourNullDateField,getdate())                   -- Will return right now

      ,coalesce(YourNullDateField,getdate())                 -- Will return right now
      ,coalesce(YourNullDateField,OtherNullField, getdate()) -- Will also return right now
```

Combining one of these with the `datediff` function gives you what the other comments and answers have provided:

```
-- Both of these will return the same result:
select datediff(day,
               ,StartDate
               ,coalesce(EndDate, getdate())
               )

      ,datediff(day,
               ,StartDate
               ,isnull(EndDate, getdate())
               )
```